# JavaScript: Convert UTC time to local time using timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I have a UTC date time string and time zone name. I am getting this from a third party API. I need to convert the UTC time to local time of that timezone using JavaScript/NodeJS as well as get that time zone's current time. Is there any library/method available for the same?

```
var timezone = "America/New_York";//This will always be in Olson format.
var UTCTime = "2017-09-03T02:00:00Z";
var localTime; //I need to find the equivalent of UTCTime for America/New_York
var currentTime; //Current time of time zone America/New_York
```

Comment: Helpful resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: moment (http://momentjs.com/docs/) is a very powerful and popular Date manipulation library, most likely your requirement can be covered by it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in few ways:

```
var options = {
    timeZone: "America/New_York",
    year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'
};

var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);

var UTCTime = "2017-09-03T02:00:00Z";
var localTime = formatter.format(new Date(UTCTime));
var currentTime = formatter.format(new Date()); console.log(currentTime, localTime);
```

Or you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.

You can use Intl.DateTimeFormat in the most modern browsers.
[Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) has been supported by most modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) which returns the offset in minutes. You can then modify your date to the corresponding return of the function.

You may also want to look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) which is a very useful library when it comes to javascipt dates.